# Wordpress plugin parent child relationship

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a Plugin categories importer In wordpress I have three arrays

```
<?php
$Id={'1','2,'3','4','5'};
$Title={'Electronic','Mobile','Iphone','Freezer','Lg'};
$Catid={'0','1','2','1','4'};
?>
```

Now how i maintain parent child relationship using them the child  are those which $Catid matches with $Id means Mobile is child of electronic.
I need to insert them in DB and show relationship in Wp-admin.
 I am stuck here any help is appreciable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used in my code
following conventions

```
$Id as $myid
$Title as $mytitle
$Catid as $catid

    for($i=0;$i<count($myid);$i++)
    {

        if($catid[$i]==0)
        {
            $my_cat = array('cat_name' => $mytitle[$i], 'category_description'     => 'A Cool Category', 'category_nicename' => $mytitle[$i],         'category_parent' => '');
            // Create the category
            $my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);
        }
        else {
            for($j=0;$j<count($myid);$j++)
            {
                if($myid[$j]==$catid[$i]){
                    $parent=trim($mytitle[$j]);
                    break;
                }

            }

            $query="SELECT `term_id`
FROM `wp_terms`
WHERE `name` = '$parent'";

            $res=$wpdb->get_results($query);

            foreach($res as $result)
            {
                $parent_id=$result->term_id;
            }

            //var_dump($res);die;
            $my_cat = array('cat_name' => $mytitle[$i], 'category_description'     => 'A Cool Category', 'category_nicename' => $mytitle[$i],         'category_parent' => $parent_id);
            $my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);
        }

    }
```